# Dynamic RedirectMatch Wordpress Permalink Change

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

Have a wordpress blog in an older wordpress installation located under the /blog directory.  These files have a permalink naming convention of 0000-name-of-file.html.
The new wordpress blog location is category/blog, and the new permalink file name convention is name-of-file-0000.html

I was thinking that I would be able to create a rule to redirect/rewrite the name dynamically.  But this does not work.

Anyone have any thoughts on what I am doing wrong.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]{4})-(\d+)\.html $http://www.xyz.com/$2-$1.html [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule as first rule in `blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.+)$ /category/blog/$2-$1 [R=302,L]
```